# How don't I get HTML entities in menu tabs?

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm setting up a group of tabs in (what I think is the) usual way.  One of these tabs has a title with an ampersand:

```
$items['user/%user/q-and-a/all'] = array(
    'title' => "Q & A home",
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
```

When the page containing this tab is rendered, the ampersand shows up in its entity form, i.e., `Q &amp; A home`.  How can I get this rendered on the page as a real ampersand?  FWIW, I'm not doing anything funny on the page template; it's a pretty stock page.tpl.php.

Comment: How is the menu being built/rendered? The link titles must be getting run through `check_plain` (or `htmlentities`) twice...core doesn't do that which suggests you might have something custom acting on them in the theme. Or maybe an overzealous custom/contrib module

Comment: That was my thought, too.  Thanks; I haven't found one of those calls yet, but I'll keep looking...